# Getting array out of bounds exception even though I have checked for the bounds

Tags: java, data-structures, stack, queue, maze

I am writing a JAVA program that uses both a Stack and Queue to solve a maze. I am almost done. But my code crashes with Array index out of bounds. It's obvious that it goes out of my maze.

[image]

I have already made a method that checks if the index is within bounds but it seems like its not working and still giving me an error.

Maybe the solution is staring at me right in the face but I can't seem to figure out the problem
Sorry about my amateur code practice...I am just learning.
I would really appreciate if someone could help me out.
Thanks.

```
/*
The input is a simple text file: 
And this is what the output should look like. 

Please enter the input file name (.txt only):
sample1.txt
Processing sample1.txt...
The initial maze is:
#######
#...#S#
#F#...#
#######
The path found using a stack is:

#######
#***#S#
#F#***#
#######

Path from start to finish: (1, 5) (2, 5) (2, 4) (2, 3) (1, 3) (1, 2) (1, 1) (2, 1)
The path found using a queue is:

#######
#***#S#
#F#***#
#######

Path from start to finish: (1, 5) (2, 5) (2, 4) (2, 3) (1, 3) (1, 2) (1, 1) (2, 1)
Processing terminated normally.
*/
```

```
// this'll test the type of square
enum SquareType{
    START,
    FINISH,
    PATH,
    WALL,

}

// This will represent one location in the maze, it will stores information about
// that location, and update whether it is a path or a wall and whether it is
// a start/origin or finish/destination.
public class Position {
    // instance variables
    // these are the coordinates
    private int row;
    private int col;
    private SquareType type;
    private boolean visited;
    private Position prev; // reference to the previous position on the path

    // getters and setters
    public int getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    public void setRow(int row) {
        this.row = row;
    }

    public int getCol() {
        return col;
    }

    public void setCol(int col) {
        this.col = col;
    }

    public SquareType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(SquareType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public boolean isVisited() {
        return visited;
    }

    public void setVisited(boolean visited) {
        this.visited = visited;
    }

    public Position getPrev() {
        return prev;
    }

    public void setPrev(Position prev) {
        this.prev = prev;
    }



    private static final String wall = "#";
    private static final String start = "S";
    private static final String finish = "F";
    private static final String path = ".";


    // reference to the previous position


    // Constructor accepts row, col and type
    public Position(int row, int col, SquareType type) {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
        this.type = type;
        // the constructor should set the other fields to default values
        this.visited = false;
        this.prev = null;
    }

    // checks and indicates whether the position has been visited


    // displays the maze or lists the path
    public String pathString() {
        String myString = null;
        if (type == SquareType.WALL) {
            myString = wall;
        }
        if (type == SquareType.FINISH) {
            myString = finish;
        }
        if (type == SquareType.PATH) {
            myString = path;
        }
        if (type == SquareType.START) {
            myString = start;
        }
        return myString;
    }

    public String printCoordinates() {
        String str = "";
        str += " (";
        str += row;
        str += ", ";
        str += col;
        str += ") ";

        return str;
    }
}

// This class will store Positions,
// Queue will be implemented using Linked List
// this will be a circular linked list with end pointer

public class Queue {
    public class Node{
        public Position item;
        public Node next;

        public Node(Position item, Node next) {
            this.item = item;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

    private Node last; // a pointer to the last node in the queue

    // Constructor
    public Queue() {
        last = null;
    }

    // checks if my list is empty
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return last == null;
    }

    // inserts at the end of the list
    public void enqueue(Position item) {
        // last nodes's next pointer will point at new node
        // then point the new node to the first node
        // make the last point at new node
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            last.next = new Node(item, last.next);
            last = last.next;
        } else {
            // if it is the only node then make it point to itself
            last = new Node(item, null);
            last.next = last;
        }
    }

    // remove the front item and return it
    public Position dequeue() {
        // the first node has to be removed
        // i.e. last's next node
        // and last points at the end

        Position pos = null;
        if (isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Queue list is empty");
        } else {
            pos = last.next.item;
            // if there's more than one node
            if (last.next != last) {
                last.next = last.next.next;
            }else {
                // if there's only 1 node, delete it
                last = null;
            }
        }
        return pos;
    }

    // returns the front item
    // i.e. the last item's next item
    public Position front() {
        Position result = null;
        if (isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Queue list is empty");
        } else {
            result = last.next.item;
        }
        return result;
    }

}

// This class will store Positions
// Stack will be implemented using an array
public class Stack {
    private int top; // index of the top item (if any)
    private Position[] stack;

    // Constructor
    public Stack(int size){
        stack = new Position[size];
        top = -1;
    }

    // Pushes on top of the list
    public void push(Position data) {
        // check if the stack is full
        if (isFull()) {
            System.out.println("Stack is full");
        }else{
            top++; // increment top first
            stack[top] = data;
        }
    }

    // remove top item from stack and return it
    public Position pop() {
        Position topItem = null;
        if (isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Stack is empty");
        } else {
            // store the top item of the stack in topItem
            topItem = stack[top];
            stack[top] = null;
            top--;
        }
        return topItem;
    }

    // returns the top item of the stack
    public Position peek() {
        Position result = null;

        if (!isEmpty()) {
            result = stack[top];
        } else {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Stack is empty");
        }
        return result;
    }

    // returns the size
    public int size() {
        return top + 1;
    }

    // checks if my stack is empty
    // if my top index is -1 then stack is empty
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return top == -1;
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        return top == stack.length - 1;
    }

}
```

The Position, Stack and Queue class are fine. The trouble is in the Maze class.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Maze {
    // 2D array of Positions
    private Position[][] posArray;
    private int row;
    private int col;
    private Position start;
    private Position finish;

//    private static final String wall = "#";
//    private static final String start = "S";
//    private static final String finish = "F";
//    private static final String path = ".";

    //Maze constructor
    // read input file, create 2D array of appropriate size
    // then fill the array

    public Maze(String inputfile) {
        FileReader fileReaderIn;
        BufferedReader fileIn;
        String inputLine;
        try {
            fileReaderIn = new FileReader(inputfile);
            fileIn = new BufferedReader(fileReaderIn);
            String stringArray; // array to store words
            inputLine = fileIn.readLine();
            System.out.println("Processing line: " + inputfile);
            System.out.println();
            String size[];
            while (inputLine != null) {
                size = inputLine.split(" "); // splits the first line by space.
                //size[0] is the row
                // size[1] is the col
                row = Integer.parseInt(size[0]);
                col = Integer.parseInt(size[1]);
                posArray = new Position[row][col]; // create an array of size row x col

                // we have created the array reading the first line
                // now we have to read the next lines
                // and fill the array with what we have read.

                // read the next line till the number of rows
                for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
                    //inputLine = fileIn.readLine();
                    String nextLine = fileIn.readLine(); // keep reading the next line
                    String[] charArray = nextLine.split("");
                    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                        SquareType type = null;
                        if (charArray[j] .equals("#")) { // checking if the character read is equal to #
                            type = SquareType.WALL;
                        } else if (charArray[j] .equals( ".")) { // checking if the character read is equal to .
                            type = SquareType.PATH;
                        }else if (charArray[j]. equals("F")) { // checking if the character read is equal to F
                            type = SquareType.FINISH;
                            finish=new Position(i,j,SquareType.FINISH); // save Finish position when found, don't need the search method
                        }else if (charArray[j].equals("S")) { // checking if the character read is equal to S
                            type = SquareType.START;
                            start= new Position(i,j,SquareType.START); // saves the start position when found, don't need the search method
                        }
                        posArray[i][j] = new Position(i, j,type ); // creating our position type and filling the array
                    }
                    // now you have to separete the string line into characters
                    // and insert them into columns.
                }
                // read the next line and then store it in a string
                // separate the string into characters then put those characters in the array

                inputLine = fileIn.readLine(); // might not need this. you already have a loop for row

            }
            fileIn.close();

            //stackPath(start, finish, posArray);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    // This method searches using Stack
    // returns true if the search is successful
    public void stackSearch() {
        //Boolean result = false;
        Position current; // tracker

        // add start position to data structure
        Stack myStack = new Stack(row * col); // size of stack
        // add start position to stack
        myStack.push(start);
        // mark start position as visited
        start.isVisited();
        // while(stack not empty)
        while (!myStack.isEmpty()) {
                current = myStack.pop(); // curr = remove position from stack
                Position neighbour;
                if (current.equals(finish)) { // if (current is the finish)
                    //result = true;
                    // exit search
                    break; // maze is solved
                }

                // for (each neighbour of current that is an unvisited path)
                // while !neighbour.isVisited
                // if (!posArray[current.getRow() - 1][current.getCol()].equals("#") && !isVisited)

                else {
                    Position up = posArray[current.getRow() - 1][current.getCol()];    // UP
                    Position down = posArray[current.getRow() + 1][current.getCol()];  // DOWN
                    Position left = posArray[current.getRow()][current.getCol() - 1];   // LEFT
                    Position right = posArray[current.getRow()][current.getCol() + 1];  // RIGHT


                    if (isInMaze(up) && !up.equals("#") && !(up.isVisited())) { // if UP has .

                        neighbour = up; // UP is neighbour
                       // neighbour.isVisited();
                        neighbour.setVisited(true); // set UP to visited
                        // UP neighbour = current.getRow() - 1][current.getCol()
                        myStack.push(neighbour); // add neighbour to stack
                        // prev = current;
                        neighbour.setPrev(current); // we need to keep track of the previous node

                    }

                    if (isInMaze(down) && !down.equals("#") && !(down.isVisited())) { // if DOWN has .
                        neighbour = down; // DOWN is neighbour
                        neighbour.setVisited(true); // set DOWN to visited
                        myStack.push(neighbour); // add neighbour to stack
                        neighbour.setPrev(current); // we need to keep track of the previous node
                    }
                    if (isInMaze(left) && !left.equals("#") && !(left.isVisited())) { // if LEFT has .
                        neighbour = left; // LEFT is neighbour
                        neighbour.setVisited(true); // set LEFT to visited
                        myStack.push(neighbour);
                        neighbour.setPrev(current); // we need to keep track of the previous node

                    }
                    if (isInMaze(right) && !right.equals("#") && !right.isVisited()) { // if RIGHT has .
                        neighbour = right;
                        neighbour.setVisited(true); // set RIGHT to visited
                        myStack.push(neighbour);
                        neighbour.setPrev(current); // we need to keep track of the previous node
                    }
                }

            //result = true;
        }
        printMaze();
        //return result;
    }

    // This method searches using Queue
    // returns true if the search is successful
    public void queueSearch() {
        //Boolean result = false;
        Position current = null; // tracker
        Position neighbour = null;

        // add start position to data structure
        Queue myQueue = new Queue();
        // add start position to queue
        myQueue.enqueue(start);

        // mark start position as visited
        start.isVisited();
        // while(stack not empty)
        while (!myQueue.isEmpty()) {
            current = myQueue.dequeue(); // removes and returns the first node

            //neighbour.setPrev(null);
            if (current.equals(finish)) { // if (current is the finish)
                //result = true;
                // exit search
                break; // maze is solved
            }

            // for (each neighbour of current that is an unvisited path)
            // while !neighbour.isVisited
            // if (!posArray[current.getRow() - 1][current.getCol()].equals("#") && !isVisited)
            else {
                Position up = posArray[current.getRow() - 1][current.getCol()];    // UP
                Position down = posArray[current.getRow() + 1][current.getCol()];  // DOWN
                Position left = posArray[current.getRow()][current.getCol() - 1];   // LEFT
                Position right = posArray[current.getRow()][current.getCol() + 1];  // RIGHT

                if (isInMaze(up) && !up.equals("#") && !(up.isVisited())) { // if UP has .
                    neighbour = up; // UP is neighbour
                    neighbour.setVisited(true); // set UP to visited
                    myQueue.enqueue(neighbour); // add neighbour to Queue
                    // prev = current;
                    neighbour.setPrev(current); // we need to keep track of the previous node
                }
                if (isInMaze(down) && !down.equals("#") && !(down.isVisited())) { // if DOWN has .
                    neighbour = down; // DOWN is neighbour
                    neighbour.setVisited(true); // set DOWN to visited
                    myQueue.enqueue(neighbour); // add neighbour to Queue
                    neighbour.setPrev(current); // we need to keep track of the previous node
                }
                if (isInMaze(left) && !left.equals("#") && !(left.isVisited())) { // if LEFT has .
                    neighbour = left; // LEFT is neighbour
                    neighbour.setVisited(true); // set LEFT to visited
                    myQueue.enqueue(neighbour); // add neighbour to Queue
                    neighbour.setPrev(current); // we need to keep track of the previous node
                }
                if (isInMaze(right) && !right.equals("#") && !(right.isVisited())) { // if RIGHT has .
                    neighbour = right;
                    neighbour.setVisited(true); // set RIGHT to visited
                    myQueue.enqueue(neighbour); // add neighbour to Queue
                    neighbour.setPrev(current); // we need to keep track of the previous node

                }
                // mark here if VISITED
                // I have the coordinates for Position and I can set the type to *
                // neighbour.setMarked() or current as visited
                // mark that position
                // mark(neighbour.getRow(), neighbour.getCol(), "*");
                // set neighbour to marked, return a boolean with that position
                // then in the print statement check which ones are marked
                // print the ones that are marked with *
                // i already marked the visited ones as true
            }

            //result = true;
        }
        printMaze();
       // return result;

    }

    //true if cell is within maze
    public boolean isInMaze(int i, int j) {
        if (i >= 0 && i<this.row && j>= 0 && j<this.col) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    //true if cell is within maze
    public boolean isInMaze(Position pos) {
        return isInMaze(pos.getRow(), pos.getCol());
    }


    // print the maze
    public void printMaze() {
        for (int i=0; i<row; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<col; j++) {
                System.out.print(posArray[i][j].pathString());
                //System.out.print(' ');
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    // clear all visited cells
    // resetMaze() : reset all Positions in the maze to unvisited
    public void resetMaze() {
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                posArray[i][j].setVisited(false); // clear visited to not visited
            }
        }
    }
    // marks the visited position to *
    public void mark(int i, int j, SquareType type) {
        Position temp = posArray[i][j];
        temp.setType(type);
    }

//    public Position[][] array(int i, int j, Position[][] posArray) { // keep track of positions that are .
//        Position[][] dot = new Position[1][4];
//
//        if (!posArray[i - 1][j].equals("#")) {// up}
//            dot[0][0] = posArray[i - 1][j];
//        }
//            if (!posArray[i + 1][j].equals("#")) {
//                dot[0][1] = posArray[i+1][j];
//            }  // down
//
//            if (!posArray[i][j - 1].equals("#")) {
//                dot[0][2] = posArray[i][j - 1];
//            }; // left
//            if (!posArray[i][j + 1].equals("#")) {
//                ; // right}
//                dot[0][3] = posArray[i][j + 1];
//            }
//        return dot;
//    }



}
```

Comment: You pasted a LOT of code here, but forgot to add the exception itself.

Comment: did you put too many items in the stack? Your stack doesn't grow if it fills up.

Comment: @amit I posted the photo and apparently its on imgur.

Comment: My stack is alright. @AminM

Comment: ############
#.#........#
#.#.######.#
#.#....#...#
#.###.F#.#.#
#...####.#.#
#.#.#..#.#.#
#.#.#.##.#.#
#S#......#.#
############
Printing maze using Stack
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 12 out of bounds for length 12
 at Maze.stackSearch(Maze.java:113)
 at Main.main(Main.java:14)

Comment: So I was able to fix the problem by changing the stack codes in else condition from

```
if (isInMaze(up) && !up.equals("#") && !(up.isVisited()))

```

to 

```
if (isInMaze(up) && up.equals(".") && !(up.isVisited()))

``` 

but now my stack is not updating, it is printing the same code.